Conflicting Peer dependency while add PWA to Angular 17 Project
Getting conflicting peer dependency error while adding PWA.
I am using Angular 17 with standalone components. I am trying to add PWA to the application but while trying to add PWA with ng command I am getting error with conflicting peer dependency
Command used:
ng add @angular/pwa
I am getting the following error:
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@17.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^17.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.2.4" from @angular/animations@17.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^17.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @angular/material@17.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^17.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@angular/material-moment-adapter)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser, @angular/platform-server, @swimlane/ngx-charts)
npm ERR!   12 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/compiler, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/service-worker@"^17.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@17.3.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.3" from @angular/service-worker@17.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/service-worker
npm ERR!     @angular/service-worker@"^17.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 

Angular Package.json looks like this:
**Package.json**:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.2.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.5.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2"
  }
}


Update the angular version using ng update.

Try "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" to resolve the dependency issues as suggested in the error.
